# MYSQL difference between two datetime

Tags: mysql, window-functions, lag, lead, timestampdiff

I have the following table.

**table1**:

```
id_user | action |  time 
--------+--------+----------------------
1       | 2      | '2009-05-18 11:45:42'
1       | 2      | '2009-05-18 11:45:45'
1       | 3      | '2009-05-18 11:45:50'
1       | 2      | '2009-05-18 11:46:50'
```

And I want to achieve result where the column `timediff` contains timediff with the previous row in seconds.

**table2**

```
id_user | action | timediff
--------+--------+----------
1       | 2      | 3
1       | 2      | 5
1       | 3      | 60
```

I tried this query, but It did not work:

```
SELECT
    id_user,action, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,LEAD(time),time) OVER (PARTITION BY id_user, ORDER BY time) AS timediff
FROM table1
```

... but it throws an error. :/

I read other answers, but I didn't see one that use `LEAD` or `LAG` with `TIMESTAMPDIFF` simultaneously.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you must use this:

```
SELECT id_user,
       action, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(
         SECOND, 
         time, 
         LEAD(time) OVER (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY time)
       )  AS timediff 
FROM table1
```

The [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function's 2nd and 3d arguments are datetime expressions and the 2nd is subtracted from the 3d.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mLZkxdy3xsS7cxRGXAPBJy/0).
Results:

```
| id_user | action | timediff |
| ------- | ------ | -------- |
| 1       | 2      | 3        |
| 1       | 2      | 5        |
| 1       | 3      | 60       |
| 1       | 2      |          |
```

Comment: Thanks! you really help me!